# gsutil create signed url for upload - 404 error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm trying to create a signed url for uploading a file to my google cloud store. Here is the command I'm using:

```sh
gsutil -D  -i <service email with IAM permission>   signurl -m RESUMABLE -d 1h -c image/jpg -u gs://<bucket name>/<new object name>
```

I am getting this error:

```sh
NotFoundException: 404 Requested entity was not found.
```

What I don't understand is what is the "missing entity". The object doesn't exist in the bucket yet, so of course it's not there. Do I need to have a "dummy" object in place before I can upload? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you can try this command?

`gsutil -i <service account email> signurl -m RESUMABLE -d 1h -c image/jpg -u gs://<bucket name>/<new object name>` also are you sure the service account exists and have the due permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a service account that does not exist or that you do not have permission to use.